# Appending a table column to a table with a span tag inside the td tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I am trying to append a table column to a table row.  I have the following code

```
  var row2 = $("<tr class='header' />").attr("id", "SiteRow");
       row2.append($("<td id='FirstRowSite' <span> <img id='Plus' src='../images/Plus.png' > </span> />").text( UniqueSites[i].HubName));
$("#Overview").append(row2);
```

This appends the row just fine how ever the final result in html is displayed like this.

```
<td id="FirstRowSite" <span="">Acadieville</td>
```

As if it forgets my Span tag all together..  Perhaps I'm missing something small.  Can anyone help me out I want the final result to look like this.

```
<td id="FirstRowSite"><span><img id="Plus" src="../images/Plus.png"></span>Acadieville</td>
```

Comment: That's because the HTML you're appending is invalid. You haven't added the `>` to the opening `td` tag, and are missing the `</td>` completely.

Answer (score 0):

```
var row2 = $("tr.header");
row2.append("<td id='FirstRowSite'><span><img id='Plus' src='../images/Plus.png' / ></span>" + UniqueSites[i].HubName + "</td>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply like this :

```
var row2 = $("<tr class='header' />").attr("id", "SiteRow");
       row2.append('<td id="FirstRowSite"><span><img id="Plus" src="../images/Plus.png"></span>'+ UniqueSites[i].HubName +'</td>');
$("#Overview").append(row2);
```

You can append html directly.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
$("tr.header").append("<td id='FirstRowSite'><span><img id='Plus' src='../images/Plus.png' / ></span>" + UniqueSites[i].HubName + "</td>");
```